# Angular 2 pass data parent to child component

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, angular2-template

I have two components its called app.component and child.component. I want to pass the data from parent to child. My code is below. Where am i making mistake?

app.component.ts

```
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  entryComponents:[ChildComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

child.component.ts

```
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'child',
      templateUrl: './child.component.html'
    })
    export class ChildComponent {
     @Input() input :string;

}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>

<child [input]="parent to child"> </child>
```

child.component.html

```
<div>{{input}}</div>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ChildComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write `[input]="parent to child"` to the template then it means that you are refering to the parent components `this.parent to child` which doesn't exists.

You can do something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  entryComponents:[ChildComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  parentInput = 'parent to child';
}
```

then in the template:

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>

<child [input]="parentInput"> </child>
```

Source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child

Answer (score 2):

Just change this line and you are good to go

```
<child input="parent to child"> </child>
```

Or if you want to do

```
<child [input]="parent to child"> </child>
```

@echonax has alredy given the answer.