# Angular passing array from parent to child component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

Before we start, I started learning Angular about 1 week ago, don't be afraid to take it right back to basics.

So how do you do it?
In app.component.ts I have an standard array that needs to be accessable by multiple child components.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  masterArray = ['Create', 'Foo', 'Bar'];
}
```

How do pull this into child components generated by angular cli.
For example I need to use it in the navigation component to generate the navigation panel.

```
<li *ngFor = "let i of masterArray; let ind = index">
  <a>{{i}}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 pass data parent to child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43215085/angular-2-pass-data-parent-to-child-component)

Comment: My suggestion: whenever you have a question, google around and read more before creating something in SO. This is a really basic topic, and directly asking as u did is from my point of view lack of research capabilities

Comment: I'd been googling and had read multiple threads on SO, even the one linked by yourself. However I either couldn't get them to work or they were not relevant to what I'm doing

Answer (score 11):

You can make the array as input of children components.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navi.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navi.component.css']
})
export class NavigationComponent {
  @Input() masterArray : string[];
}
```

And pass the array to child component in html of parent component.

```
<app-navigation [masterArray]="masterArray"></app-navigation>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm new to Angular, also.  The HTML was what I was missing in every other answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the data needs to be accessed by multiple child components, you may want to instead create a service. The service can then hold the array and *any* component can access it.

I have a simple example here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable() 
export class DataService {
  masterArray = ['Create', 'Foo', 'Bar']; 
}
```

Then you access that data like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-navigation',
   templateUrl: './navi.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./navi.component.css']
 })
 export class NavigationComponent {

 get masterArray() { 
    return this.dataService.masterArray; 
 } 

 constructor(public dataService: DataService) { } 
}
```