# How to pass an array to a child component in angular

Tags: angular, angularjs

So I am able to pass a string to a child component but when I try to pass an array I get `[object Object]` as a string parameter.

Not sure why this is happening!

**parent component html:**

```
<app-channel-fields-list data="{{channelFields}}"></app-channel-fields-list>
```

**Where channelFields is**

```
const channelFields =[ { "name": "first_name", "description": "first name" } ]
```

**Child component html:**

```
{{data}}

<tr *ngFor=" hero in data">
    <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Child component ts:**

```
 @Input() data;
  ngOnInit() {
      console.log('data', this.data);  // this also prints [object Object], which is weird
  }
```

So, not really sure what the issue is since it works perfectly for passing strings but not arrays!

Here is a youtube video with what it actually looks like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gsmnoVhEig

I found a similar question:
[Angular passing array from parent to child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171832/angular-passing-array-from-parent-to-child-component)

But I can't get the dang thing to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because its trying to interpolate the object into a string because of the curly brackets int the parent declaration. You need to pass the array as in the following.

```
<app-channel-fields-list [data]="channelFields"></app-channel-fields-list>
```

This will allow the array to be pased to the child component - then you can iterate over it as you are doing. Also - minor thing = tyou do not need quotes around the object keys.

```
const channelFields =[ { name: "first_name", description: "my description" } ]
```

also - when iterating using *ngFor - you should use

```
<tr *ngFor="let hero of data">
    <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
</tr>
```